# PHP daisychaining unexpected behaviour

Tags: php

This is more a question out of curiosity. I'm using a php 5.6 install and I have a complex class that is dependend on several laravel models.

Now the normal flow of the object is:

- __construct()
- preInit()

  - beforeRender()
- init()
- processStuff()

It all does get called in this order without a hitch.

In beforeRender() a laravel model is assigned to an internal protected variable for quick access. I have an accessor for it `$this->getData()` which only does

```
protected function getData() 
{
      return $this->storedData;
}
```

where `$this->storedData` was assigned in beforeRender();

The model there has a method `getLore()`

if I do this in processStuff() it errors with trying to get property of non object(null)

```
protected function processStuff() {
    $lore = $this->getData()->getLore();
}
```

But if I do

```
protected function processStuff() {
     $data = $this->getData();
     $lore = $data->getLore();
}
```

it works without a hitch, when I change it back afterwards it also works without a hitch.

I do use opcache, could this be some sort of optimisation/prediction error of opcache or php itself? or is it something in php itself that can be troublesome for daisy chaining like trying to process multiple statements over several cores and it becomes a race condition?

I'm just curious to what makes this daisly chaining condition fail sometimes, but not all times.

All objects do get initailised and assigned.

Comment: There's an easy way to check. Turn off opcache and test.

Comment: just inspect $data to see the difference in behaviour

Comment: That's the problem @Code4R7 if I assign $data it works flawlessly. It is initialised, I went past the entire initialisation chain.

Comment: @JonStirling unfortunately I can't do that. It occurs on a production server. My boss might not like me experimenting with the ecommerce sites. for a 'minor' issue

Comment: @Tschallacka So you're saying you can't replicate in non-prod? Do the non-prod envs have opcache installed and enabled?

Comment: yea, but it occurs only every so often and it's nigh impossible to replicate consistently, which makes it feel like a race condition occurring to me, the call to next function completes before the return has finished. That's also why I posted this question out there, if there are others who encountered this, or who might know more about this. https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: PHP does have some limitations of not being able to handle certain objects if they're not passed to a variable, but that would show another type of error. I'm not sure what happens here either, might even be just some PHP bug. Since you have a flawless workaround, I suggest that only those with a lot of spare time should look into the issue further ;)

Comment: I agree, this doesn't need a quick answer, it's more a for curiosities sake question so I can add a why to the list of idiosyncrasies of php I have to remember